# What is the difference between Top Grossing and Top Paid in the App Store?

Tags: mac-appstore

In App Store, What is the different between **Top Grossing** and **Top Paid**?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

There are three categories: **Top Free**, **Top Paid**, and **Top Grossing**.

In the **Top Free** category, the apps with the most downloads that have a price of $0 make the list.

In the **Top Paid** category, the apps with the most downloads that have a price greater than $0 make the list.

The **Top Grossing** category lists the apps with the highest total revenue (that is, price * quantity sold + revenue from in-app purchases). A $50 app is likely to have fewer downloads than at $0.99 app. The **Top Paid** list will likely include many inexpensive apps that get purchased often. The **Top Grossing** category is to indicate which apps have the highest total spent on them.

Comment: I think the Top Grossing category also counts in-app purchases towards the revenue.

Comment: @Heng-CheongLeong: That makes sense. Does it also include in-app purchases for free apps?

Comment: @Thilo: That's correct, it measures total revenue including in app purchases and app price. There are several "Free" apps that feature on the top grossing list, this is due to the revenue generated by their in-app purchases.

Comment: Four of the apps in top-grossing right now cost $79.99 or more.